# Euclidean algoritm to get two polynomials

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, euclidean-algorithm

Determine two polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ so that $$p(x)(x^3+2x^2+3x)+q(x)(x^2+3x+2)=1$$

I know the answer, but not where it comes from.
$$p(x)=3x\\
q(x)=2x^2+3x+3$$

With Euclidean algoritm I've got that
$$(x^3+2x^2+3x)=(x^2+3x+2)(x+4)+(4x+2)\\
(x^2+3x+2)=(4x+2)(4x)+(2)\\
(4x+2)=(2)(2x+1)+(0)$$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substituting the equations you got from bottom to top, we find an expression of the gcd in terms of the two original polynomials:
\begin{align*}
2 &= (x^2+3x+2) - (4x+2)(4x) \\
&= (x^2+3x+2) - \left[ (x^3+2x^2+3x) - (x^2+3x+2)(x+4)\right](4x) \\
&= (x^2+3x+2) - (x^3+2x^2+3x)(4x) + (x^2+3x+2)(x+4)(4x) \\
&= (x^2+3x+2)\cdot(1+(x+4)(4x)) + (x^3+2x^2+3x)\cdot (-4x) \\
&= (x^2+3x+2)\cdot\underbrace{(4x^2+x+1)}_{2\,q(x)} + (x^3+2x^2+3x)\cdot \underbrace{x}_{2\,p(x)}.
\end{align*}
This can also be achieved by more efficient book keeping using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Polynomial_extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: Good point, I did not notice

Comment: So it seems the question has more than one aolution. I found $p(x)=2x$ and $q(x)=x^2-7x+\frac 12$. I assumed $p(x)=ax+b$ and $q(x)=cx^2+dx+e$ and I found a system of four Diophantine equations, one solution was that.

Comment: @sirous Indeed, since $g\cdot f + (-f)\cdot g = 0$, a solution $p\cdot f + q\cdot g = c$ always yields other solutions $(p+kg)\cdot f + (q-kf)\cdot g = c$. However, there seems to be an error in your calculation: Assuming by $\frac 1 2$ you mean $3$ (this is in $\mathbb Z_5$), the LHS evaluates to $3x^4+1$ instead of $1$.